# Python Pandas Update Dataframe Column Types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel into pandas and all column headers are datetime except first one. I want to format the datetime column headers.

This is the test data and code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {
         datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 31, 8, 00): [9.1, 8.5, 7.4, 6.5, 5.3],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 28, 9, 00): [9.2, 8.5, 7.2, 6.1, 5.2],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 03, 31, 10, 00): [9.3, 8.5, 7.1, 6.1, 5.1],
         'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns= ['ID', datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 31, 8, 00), datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 28, 9, 00), datetime.datetime(2018, 03, 31, 10, 00)])
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].columns = [x.date() for x in df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].columns]
```

I want to format datetime header to just date. eg: Update `2018-01-31 08:00:00` to `2018-01-31`.

I am use `.date()` function to achieve that. I think the way I am doing is wrong. 
Below line is not updating the  datetime column header.

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].columns = [x.date() for x in df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].columns]
```

Any ideas or pointer? [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {
         datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 31, 8, 00): [9.1, 8.5, 7.4, 6.5, 5.3],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 28, 9, 00): [9.2, 8.5, 7.2, 6.1, 5.2],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 03, 31, 10, 00): [9.3, 8.5, 7.1, 6.1, 5.1],
         'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns= ['ID', datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 31, 8, 00), datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 28, 9, 00), datetime.datetime(2018, 03, 31, 10, 00)])
df.columns = [x.date() if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x for x in df.columns]
print(df.columns)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  2018-03-31
0   1         9.1         9.2         9.3
1   2         8.5         8.5         8.5
2   3         7.4         7.2         7.1
3   4         6.5         6.1         6.1
4   5         5.3         5.2         5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {
         datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 31, 8, 00): [9.1, 8.5, 7.4, 6.5, 5.3],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 28, 9, 00): [9.2, 8.5, 7.2, 6.1, 5.2],
         datetime.datetime(2018, 03, 31, 10, 00): [9.3, 8.5, 7.1, 6.1, 5.1],
         'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*d.values()), columns= map(lambda ele: ele if isinstance(ele, str) else ele.date(), d.keys()))
df



2018-01-31  2018-02-28  2018-03-31  ID
0   9.1   9.2   9.3  1
1   8.5   8.5   8.5  2
2   7.4   7.2   7.1  3
3   6.5   6.1   6.1  4
4   5.3   5.2   5.1  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.15.0 of pandas, you can use the [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor) accessor in order to get the date (and ignore the time) which will return `datetime.date dtype`

```
df['dates_without_time'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
```